# what is the equivalent Range Function (VBA) in C#

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am in an process migration VBA to C#. I do not know how to use or what is the equivalent in C#. Let me show you the line of code:

```
Range("U1:U" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=if(rc[-1]=""" & qyyyy & """,rc[-15],rc[-14])"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("U1:U" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 =  $@"=if(rc[-1]=""{qyyyy}"",rc[-15],rc[-14])";
```

First, string concatentation is `+` in C# vs. `&` in VB.NET.

Second this uses string interpolation instead of concatenation because it saves us from having to add the extra quotes to terminate the strings.

It works like this:

```
var x = 1;
var y = $"The number is {x}.";
// y = "The number is 1."
```

The `$` indicates that the string is interpolated, which means that `{qyyyy}` is converted to a string.

The `@` in front of the string means that characters in the string aren't escaped. That allows us to use `""` within the string to represent a single `"`. Otherwise we'd have to do this:

```
$"=if(rc[-1]=\"{qyyyy}\",rc[-15],rc[-14])";
```

...using `\` to escape the quotes. That works too but to me it's slightly more confusing to read. For people used to certain languages it might be better.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It just made me smile. I'm going to delete it and give up my 8 hard-earned points.